How to set up free trial on Enupal Stripe Plugin?
I’m encountering some issues and need help setting up a free trial using Enupal Stripe plugin.
I don't have to use custom plan, have to use custom code.
My code is like this.
        {{% set paymentFormTemp = licenceTemp.stripePaymentForm.one() %}

        {% set options = {
            checkoutSuccessUrl: siteUrl ~ 'products/' ~ slug  ~ '/thank-you',
            checkoutCancelUrl: siteUrl ~ 'products/' ~ slug  ~ '/buy',
        } %}
        {{ paymentFormTemp.paymentForm(options) }}


